# contar el numero de repetiiones y ordenar un arreglo

Tags: javascript

tengo un arreglo con nombres y necesito contar cuantas veces se repite cada nombre y luego ordenarlo de mayor a menor...aqui el codigo:

```
let tempArray=['Ana', 'Oswaldo', 'Oswaldo', 'Oswaldo','Raul', 'Celia', 'María', 'Antonio']

let contar=tempArray.reduce((acum, item)=>{
   acum[item]=(acum[item] || 0)+1
   return acum

},{})
console.log(contar)
```

El resultado de esto es:

```
{Ana: 1,Oswaldo: 3, Raul: 1, Celia: 1, María: 1, Antonio: 1}
```

el problema es que es un objeto y no se como pasarlo a un arreglo u ordenar esto o alguna otra sugerencia...disculpen estoy comenzando...

la salida la quisiera ordenada, por nombre y por cantidad:
Ana:1 ,Antonio:1, Celia:1, Raul:1, Maria:1, Oswaldo:3...ideal en un arreglo, bueno no se si se pueda....

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que esperas tener en el arreglo? ¿Solo en número de repeticiones? ¿Solo el numbre?¿Podrías colocer un ejemplo de la salida esperada? Parece que vas por buen camino.

Comment: ordenarlo de mayor a menor...ya edite la ṕregunta, gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los objetos no se pueden ordenar, pero si convertimos todo a un arreglo después de contar los votos, lograremos el cometido.

```js
let tempArray = ['Ana', 'Oswaldo', 'Oswaldo', 'Oswaldo', 'Raul', 'Celia', 'María', 'Antonio']

let contar = tempArray.reduce((acum, item) => {
  //Necesitas validar si la propiedad existe, si no es asi
  // la inicias en 0

  if (!acum[item]) acum[item] = 0
  //Sumas 1 por cada coincidencia.
  acum[item]++
    return acum

}, {})

//Separamos los datos en un arreglo, cada uno como objeto. 

let ordenado = Object.keys(contar)
  .map(key => ({
    nombre: key,
    valor: contar[key]
  }))
   //Ordenamos el arreglo de menor a mayor comparando la propiedad valor. 
  .sort((a, b) => a.valor > b.valor ? 1 : -1)


console.log(ordenado)
```

Comment: excelente!!!!!! muchisimas gracias :)